# is there a way to loop this in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to convert some of my formulas into vba. is there a simple way to loop this in VBA.

```
BB4 =(ABS(BA4-AZ4)+ABS(BA4-AZ5)+ABS(BA4-AZ6)+ABS(BA4-AZ7)+ABS(BA4-AZ8)+ABS(BA4-AZ9)+ABS(BA4-AZ10)+ABS(BA4-AZ11)+ABS(BA4-AZ12)+ABS(BA4-AZ13)+ABS(BA4-AZ14)+ABS(BA4-AZ15)+ABS(BA4-AZ16)+ABS(BA4-AZ17)+ABS(BA4-AZ18)+ABS(BA4-AZ19)+ABS(BA4-AZ20)+ABS(BA4-AZ21)+ABS(BA4-AZ22)+ABS(BA4-AZ23))/20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely! You can make a for loop

```
Dim i As Integer, sum As Double
For i = 4 To 23
    sum = sum + ABS(Cells(53,4).value-Cells(51,i).value)
Next i
Cells(54,4) = sum/20
```

Comment: i'm getting a compile error on "sum as float". how do i fix that?

Comment: Oops! I meant `As Double`. IIRC, `float` doesn't exist in VBA.

Comment: i figured it out too that it needed to be double and now it works! excellent! thanks for you help

Comment: No worries! Thanks for asking when there was an error instead of just assuming I was trying to intentionally mislead you!